# Error in one vba workbook causes other independent workbooks to stop running

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a number of programs that monitor devices and records data.  The programs are continuously running. I'm usually monitoring several devices using separate workbooks that are independent from each other. However, if one program gets an error, all of VBA stops, including those other programs.
Is there a way to have separate instances of VBA? So if one faults the others can still run? Thanks.

Comment: Running under different users? On separate machines?

Comment: Run separate instances of Excel?  Use error handling to prevent your code from just halting?

Comment: @TimWilliams. All excel instances are lumped into the same instance of VBA. I could do better at error handling, but sometimes I also want to write new code, and that is difficult if other codes in other workbooks are running.

Comment: @SolarMike. Neither of those options are available to me. I just find astonishing that I can't have multiple instances of VBA. Thank you though.

Comment: I was suggesting you run different instances of Excel if you need errors in one method to not block any other code from running.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim. What I meant was you can have 10 different instances of excel open. But the VBA code for all ten, will share the same instance of VBA. If one code faults, they all do.

Comment: That's true for separate *workbooks* in one instance, but not for workbooks in different instances.  To start a new instance, hold down the Alt key while opening Excel - it will ask you if you mean to start a new instance.  Or you can create a new instance in VBA using `CreateObject()`

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you so much. I guess what I thought was multiple instances was really only one. I mean it looked like multiple instances. But the Alt key did the trick. I'm new to stack overflow, I guess your supposed to submit an answer and I submit it as the answer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an error in one workbook not to affect running code in another, you can use separate instances of Excel to run each macro.

To start a new instance, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while opening Excel - it will ask you if you mean to start a new instance. Or you can create a new instance from VBA using `CreateObject()`